# How does git keep track of the commit hash marked with a fixup/squash flag?

Tags: git, rebase, squash, fixup

I know that `git commit --fixup <commit A's hash>` can make a commit B that will be combined with commit A, when executing `git rebase -i --autosquash`.

And when I run `git log`, my commit log looks something like

```
commit <commit B's hash>
Author: xxx
Date:   xxx

fixup! commit A's comment

commit <commit A's hash>
Author: xxx
Date:   xxx

commit A's comment
```

To me, the fixup commit looks nothing different from a normal commit except the comment is preceded with a "fixup!".

I wonder how and where git keeps track of the fact that **`commit B` is a fixup commit marked with `<commit A's hash>`**, if it does at all; and if that is the case, is there a `git log` equivalent that allows me to access `<commit A's hash>` along with `commit B`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***(Disclaimer: this answer is based on observations)***

It doesn't keep track of which commit to fixup, it looks for it when you do a rebase and uses the commit message to find the right one.

I tried the following:

1. Created a new repository
2. Made a few commits
3. Made 2 commits, both with the message "initial"
4. I then made a fixup commit that fixed the last of those two

   ```
   git commit --fixup bb4adbd
   ```

The log now looks like this:

```
λ git lg
* 21e0572: (5 minutes ago) fixup! initial (HEAD -> master)
| Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen <lasse@vkarlsen.no> (Wed, 16 Jan 2019 17:32:51 +0100)
|
* bb4adbd: (5 minutes ago) initial
| Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen <lasse@vkarlsen.no> (Wed, 16 Jan 2019 17:32:38 +0100)
|
* e6549e4: (9 minutes ago) initial
| Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen <lasse@vkarlsen.no> (Wed, 16 Jan 2019 17:28:59 +0100)
|
* a311a82: (9 minutes ago) second
| Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen <lasse@vkarlsen.no> (Wed, 16 Jan 2019 17:28:12 +0100)
|
* 2a5ca27: (10 minutes ago) initial
  Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen <lasse@vkarlsen.no> (Wed, 16 Jan 2019 17:27:12 +0100)
```

If I do this:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Then git suggests this:

```
pick e6549e4 initial
fixup 21e0572 fixup! initial
pick bb4adbd initial
```

Here git is trying to fixup my first "initial" commit, which is not the one I told it to fixup earlier.

However, if I just do `HEAD~2`, it suggests this:

```
pick bb4adbd initial
fixup 21e0572 fixup! initial
```

Which means that git doesn't track which commit this is about, at all, it simply records a `fixup! <commit message>` on the end of the commit message of the fixup commit.

---

A guess as to why it does this, instead of recording the SHA, would be that this would survive a rebase, a cherry-pick, etc. Additionally, this might've been added without a real way to record this sha in a proper way, because if it did record the sha of the commit it fixed, that record would either prevent a rebase, or would have to be modified as well.

Comment: I may have enabled autosquash by default.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how `git commit --squash` works then? How does it keep the comment while keeping track of the commit that it wants to combine to?